# How to get the value of another function synchronously

Tags: kotlin, websocket, ktor

I am using the ktor websocket module
When I send data to the client, how do I get the data back from the client after this send?

```
    val result = serverSession.send(json)
    // result
```

Just like this

It is actually the Unit type
But I want to get the String

Comment: Should I use a timer to wait for the results? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are great examples on official site of `Ktor`.

If you are server-side, check this link (https://ktor.io/docs/websocket.html#handle-single-session) and the below example.

```kotlin
webSocket("/echo") {
            send("Please enter your name")
            for (frame in incoming) {
                when (frame) {
                    is Frame.Text -> {
                        val receivedText = frame.readText()
                        if (receivedText.equals("bye", ignoreCase = true)) {
                            close(CloseReason(CloseReason.Codes.NORMAL, "Client said BYE"))
                        } else {
                            send(Frame.Text("Hi, $receivedText!"))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

If you are client-side, check this link (https://ktor.io/docs/websocket-client.html#example) and the below example.

```kotlin
client.webSocket(method = HttpMethod.Get, host = "127.0.0.1", port = 8080, path = "/echo") {
            while(true) {
                val othersMessage = incoming.receive() as? Frame.Text
                println(othersMessage?.readText())
                val myMessage = Scanner(System.`in`).next()
                if(myMessage != null) {
                    send(myMessage)
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: thanks But my expression seems to be inaccurate, I want to implement the ws server to send a data, and then wait for the return of the client to synchronize the execution of the next method

Comment: `val result = send(Frame.Text("{"action":"get_name"}")` just like http get

Comment: Since WebSocket is an async protocol, the `send` method cannot return the received text the right way. You could make your own function that, sending and receiving message in sync. Like this. `send(frame); val recvMsg = ( incoming.receive() as? Frame.text)?.readText()`